# Equation output is in terms of e?

Tags: output-formatting

I have a Mathematica notebook containing the following:

```
epsilon = 80.0
Rs = 0.52
qo = -0.834
RzOH = 0.58588
Rw = 1.4
epsilonW = 10.0
beta = 1/0.6
Ri = 1

p1 := -166*(1 - (1/epsilon))
p2[q_] := q^2 / (Ri + Rs)

p3[q_] := Log (e^(-1*beta*E2Pplus[q]) + Exp[-1*beta*E2Pmin[q]])
p4[q_] := Log (e^(-1*beta*ESPDplus[q]) + Exp[-1*beta*ESPDmin[q]])

E2Pplus[q_] := ((332*q*qo)/
    epsilonW)*((1/(Ri + Rw) - (1/(Ri + Rw + RzOH))))    
E2Pmin[q_] := ((332*q*qo)/
    epsilonW)*((1/(Ri + Rw) - (1/(Ri + Rw - RzOH))))

ESPDplus[q_] := (332*q*qo*RzOH)/(epsilonW*(Ri + Rw)^2)
ESPDmin[q_] := -(332*q*qo*RzOH)/(epsilonW*(Ri + Rw)^2)

deltaG[q_] := p1*p2[q]*(p3[q]/p4[q])
```

When I evaluate the code and try an input, such as deltaG[1] I get output that looks like the following:

```
-((107.845 (0.00200945 + e^3.77292))/(0.00915041 + e^4.69396))
```

Does anyone know how I can make this so it is not printed in terms of e, but rather as an actual number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct two errors :

1. Replace `Log(...)` by `Log[...]`
2. Replace `e` by `E`

Then `deltaG[1]` returns `-86.6838`

Comment: Thank you! I figured it may have been something with syntax. Just my lack of mathematica knowledge shining through!